# shiny selectInput misorder factor labels on categorical number range in dropbown bec alphabetic

Tags: r, shiny

New user.

Drop down menu from `selectInput` in `shiny` app alphabetizes categorical options. I'm using the following code with IPEDS INSTSIZE (institution size) providing the categorical data.

`selectInput("size"
                    , "2. Choose Institution Size:"
                    , as.character(levels(as.factor(ipeds$INSTSIZE)))
                    , selectize=TRUE),`

The auto alphabetize feature is usually fine for my purposes, but number ranges for institution size don't follow this pattern well. Category starting with 5,000 should start between 1,000 and 10,000. But the 1's in both 1,000 and 10,000 lead alphabetic sort to misorder. See picture below.

[image]

How might I specify in selectInput (or in underlying data) the order I want to appear in dropdown menu?

**Edit (To clarify, this may be a general issue with `factor` or `levels` and not so much `shiny::selectInput`, but I didn't see any suboptions for the prior 2 to control this.)**

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible so here's just a general way of ordering a factor variable. Consider you have a vector of numbers stored as characters: `x <- as.character(1:20)`. Then, if you run `factor(x)` they will be sorted alphabetically, i.e. 11 before 2. To avoid that you can use `factor(x, levels = sort(as.numeric(x)))`.

Comment: Not sure that helps here.  `x <- "1,000 - 4,999";  as.numeric(x)` throws an error with NAs introduced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order is determined by the order of your factor variable. Example using `mtcars`

```
x = as.factor(mtcars$cyl)

levels(x)
[1] "4" "6" "8"

x = factor(x,levels(x)[c(3,2,1)])

levels(x)
[1] "8" "6" "4"
```

Comment: thnx. I knew it had to be something ridiculously simple, but I didn't want to hard code a solution if there was a way to do suboption.